# Call/Argument Error with Asc() - Delete "unnecessary" lines in MSWord 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word

Final Update: It has been resolved in an answer below. Thanks!

---

Probelm has been NOT been resolved :-(. The script does not interact well with MSword Fields.

---

Goal: Delete lines in MSWord 2007 that contain any number of spaces, tabs, and the obvious pilcrow (paragraph mark).

Steps Taken: [I googled it and found this forum.](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?10558-Solved-How-to-delete-all-empty-rows-in-Word&p=309032)

[I then found this in a samble of a book on google and tried to modify it.](http://books.google.com/books?id=nfjMbtqE9hsC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=asc%20in%20word%20vba&source=bl&ots=SsdVufBLL4&sig=XFCGvLBFHBhOfzXflRkHIHi_coQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DF5iU4SQHNOqyASDxoDgDg&ved=0CH4Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=asc%20in%20word%20vba&f=false)

The modified is below:

```
Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim var
Dim SpaceTabCounter As Long
Dim oChar As Word.Characters

For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If Len(oPara.Range) = 1 Then
        oPara.Range.Delete
    Else
        SpaceTabCounter = 0
        Set oChar = oPara.Range.Characters
        For var = 1 To oChar.Count
            Select Case Asc(oChar(var)) '     '   '   '  'ERROR is here
                Case 32, 9
                SpaceTabCounter = SpaceTabCounter + 1
            End Select
        Next
        If SpaceTabCounter + 1 = Len(oPara.Range) Then
             ' paragraph contains ONLY spaces
            oPara.Range.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The issue is that I get an error at "Select Case Asc(oChar(var))" half way down the code. 
"Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

I'm new to VBA and...I can't figure this out. Please send your love!

Thanks

---

The error is still occuring.
Code as it stands now:

```
Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim var
Dim SpaceTabCounter As Long
Dim oChar As Word.Characters

For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If Len(oPara.Range) = 1 Then
        oPara.Range.Delete
    Else
        SpaceTabCounter = 0
        Set oChar = oPara.Range.Characters
        For var = 1 To oChar.Count
            Select Case Asc(oChar(var).Text) 'modified this line: added ".Text"
                Case 32, 9
                SpaceTabCounter = SpaceTabCounter + 1
            End Select
        Next
        If SpaceTabCounter + 1 = Len(oPara.Range) Then
             ' paragraph contains ONLY spaces
            oPara.Range.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `oChar(var)` returns a character object. You must call `cChar(var).Text` to get the actual character out.

Comment: The full line should be `Select Case Asc(oChar(var).Text)`.

Comment: Var = 1 to oChar.Count which is 17.

I changed to "Select Case Asc(oChar(var).Text)" - the same error happened.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Changing `Select Case(Asc(oChar(var))` to `Select Case Asc(oChar(var).Text)` makes your code work.

Comment: It seems that it has an issue with the specific Template that I use. I can't figure out what it is about it. There is a header and footer with fields such as "Title" and "Subject" in both the body and footer, images in the header, and bookmarks. Any idea why?

Comment: It's the in line bookmarks that were the issue. I don't know how to avoid them so I guess right before I run this part of my script, I'll put in another script to delete them all. I don't need them at this point. (They're used for data insertion points)

Comment: It wasn't the bookmarks. It seems to be fields that are giving the issue.

Comment: What kind of fields? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I'll upodad a file for ya in a minute or two.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nds50067x1gh1n1/Monticello.docx

It stops on [Title], the 2nd line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your code comes across a content control field, it reads the first character in the paragraph as an empty string. This behavior can be observed by checking the `oChar.First.Text` field in the local variables window. `Asc()` will throw an error when passed an empty string. This can be easily reproduced by running this procedure.

```
Sub throwError5()
    Debug.Print Asc("")
End Sub
```

You will need to test the value of oChar(var) to ensure it is not an empty string prior to returning its ASCII value.

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteEmptyParagraphs()
    Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
    Dim var
    Dim SpaceTabCounter As Long
    Dim oChar As Word.Characters

    For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If Len(oPara.Range) = 1 Then
            oPara.Range.Delete
        Else
            SpaceTabCounter = 0
            Set oChar = oPara.Range.Characters
            For var = 1 To oChar.Count
                If oChar(var) <> "" Then ' stops Asc from throwing runtime error 5
                    Select Case Asc(oChar(var)) ' no more errrors!
                        Case 32, 9
                            SpaceTabCounter = SpaceTabCounter + 1
                    End Select
                End If
            Next
            If SpaceTabCounter + 1 = Len(oPara.Range) Then
             ' paragraph contains ONLY spaces
                oPara.Range.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I don't work with the Word object model often, so I have no idea why the fields' first character is an empty string. Please note that my comment about having to call `oChar(index).Text` was wrong. Text is the default property of a characters item.

Comment: The work day is done and I'll check this out tomorrow. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I'm not allowed to upvote yet :-(. But if it answers it I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: It works! Thanks for your assistance. If/when I'm allowed to upvote I'll try to remember to shoot you one.

Comment: @VBAnoviceRyan No worries. Glad you're up and running. Welcome to SO.